# How to display a default fontawesome icon when icon is not registered ? (Vue, Angular or React)

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js, config, font-awesome

I use the fontawesome component named `<fa-icon>`, and I use the library approach :

```
export const faIconsDefinitionsToRegister: IconDefinition[] = [
  ...proRegularFaIcons,
  ...proSolidFaIcons,
  ...proLightFaIcons,
  ...proThinFaIcons,
  ...proDuotoneFaIcons,
];

// icons registration ...

library.add(...faIconsDefinitionsToRegister)

// configs ...
faConfig.defaultPrefix = 'far';
```

Rather than displaying nothing, I want to display for example this icon ...

```html
<!-- Angular syntax -->
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'question']"></fa-icon>

<!-- Vue syntax -->
<fa-icon :icon="['fas', 'question']"></fa-icon>

<!-- React syntax -->
<FaIcon icon={['fas', 'question']}></fa-icon>
```

... when there is an unknown, unregistred or inexisent icon

```html
<!-- Angular syntax -->
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'unknown-icon-name']"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon icon="unknown-icon-name"></fa-icon>

<!-- Vue syntax -->
<fa-icon :icon="['far', 'unknown-icon-name']"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon icon="unknown-icon-name"></fa-icon>

<!-- React syntax -->
<FaIcon icon={['far', 'unknown-icon-name']}></fa-icon>
<FaIcon icon="unknown-icon-name"></fa-icon>
```

How can I also set the default icon globally ? (If possible without css classes)

PS: I mean unknown as in "unregistred" or "inexisent". When there is an unknown icon, there is simply no icon rendered at all. So ultimately, I want a placeholder icon rather than an empty space.

Comment: This is very specific to the actual component implementation, so the question doesn't make sense for any framework in general, e.g. https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/blob/3.x/src/components/FontAwesomeIcon.js#L150-L165 . The general approach would possibly be to extend faicon comp or wrap it with another one

Comment: I see, I thought there was maybe a configurable solution included in the component I didn't see, but you are right.
I either need to make a wrapper, or create an issue/PR to add this functionality

Answer (score 3):

Can you give a try to this work around. You can replace the unknown/invalid font awesome with any content (text/image).

Live Demo **:**

```css
.fa:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" >

<i class="fa fa-questionnnn"></i> <!-- Here I am just adding the wrong icon name and it will get replaced by the content mentioned in the CSS. -->
<i class="fa fa-question"></i>
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest, cross-framework-compatible way. \f00d will be your default icon when you attempt to use an unregistered/non-existing icon

Comment: This can't work at all when we don't use `<i>` tags !
using js framework associated component render `svg > path` tags !
For example, when I use <fa-icon> in Angular, it renders `fa-icon > svg > path`; when I use fa-icon with vue, it renders `svg > path`